# How to get the list of installation paths of all the applications in windows C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winui-3

I am working on WinUI 3.0 .NET 8.0 application.
How to get the list of paths of *all* the applications in a windows system?
I tried [this](https://copyprogramming.com/howto/get-all-installed-application-in-windiws-in-csharp), but it didn't get me the **executable's name** (both WMI and Registry Key methods)
I need to provide the user with a window something like this (the Start Menu),

[image: Windows Start Menu]

Comment: Install / Uninstall has no concept of "executable name" nor path, it has icons, install date, display names, uninstall string, etc, with some of these pointing to MSIexec calls with MSI package ids. This is what "Installed Apps" UI shows you and this is what you get from WMI calls or from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall reg key

Comment: Hm.. Then I guess "Installed Apps" is not what I need

Comment: Don't know what you need, but there's not a "list of installed exe" on a Windows PC. You can also look here but it's roughly the same with more details https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/uninstall_view.html

Comment: I get it, I need my user to be able to choose an application, but I guess they would have to search for it using the file explorer on their own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a comprehensive list of installed applications using multiple methods like the registry, WMI, and checking Program Files directories for both 32-bit and 64-bit applications, you can use the following code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List<ApplicationInfo> installedApps = GetInstalledApplications();

        Console.WriteLine("List of Installed Applications:");
        foreach (var app in installedApps)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{app.Name}, {app.FullPath}");
        }
    }

    static List<ApplicationInfo> GetInstalledApplications()
    {
        List<ApplicationInfo> installedApps = new List<ApplicationInfo>();

        // Method 1: Registry
        installedApps.AddRange(GetInstalledAppsFromRegistry());

        // Method 2: WMI
        installedApps.AddRange(GetInstalledAppsFromWMI());

        // Method 3: Program Files
        installedApps.AddRange(GetInstalledAppsFromProgramFiles());

        return installedApps;
    }

    static List<ApplicationInfo> GetInstalledAppsFromRegistry()
    {
        List<ApplicationInfo> apps = new List<ApplicationInfo>();
        RegistryHelper.GetSubKeyValues(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall", apps, true);
        RegistryHelper.GetSubKeyValues(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall", apps, true);
        return apps;
    }

    static List<ApplicationInfo> GetInstalledAppsFromWMI()
    {
        List<ApplicationInfo> apps = new List<ApplicationInfo>();
        ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Product");

        using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query))
        {
            foreach (ManagementObject obj in searcher.Get())
            {
                string name = obj["Name"] as string;
                string version = obj["Version"] as string;
                apps.Add(new ApplicationInfo { Name = name, FullPath = version });
            }
        }

        return apps;
    }

    static List<ApplicationInfo> GetInstalledAppsFromProgramFiles()
    {
        List<ApplicationInfo> apps = new List<ApplicationInfo>();

        // Program Files (32-bit)
        string programFilesPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles);
        GetInstalledAppsFromDirectory(programFilesPath, apps, false);

        // Program Files (64-bit)
        string programFiles86Path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86);
        GetInstalledAppsFromDirectory(programFiles86Path, apps, true);

        return apps;
    }

    static void GetInstalledAppsFromDirectory(string directoryPath, List<ApplicationInfo> apps, bool is64Bit)
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(directoryPath))
        {
            foreach (string directory in Directory.GetDirectories(directoryPath))
            {
                string appName = new DirectoryInfo(directory).Name;
                string exePath = Path.Combine(directory, "exeName.exe"); // Replace with the actual executable name or search for it
                apps.Add(new ApplicationInfo { Name = appName, FullPath = exePath });
            }
        }
    }
}

class ApplicationInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FullPath { get; set; }
}

static class RegistryHelper
{
    public static void GetSubKeyValues(RegistryHive hive, string subKey, List<ApplicationInfo> values, bool includePath)
    {
        using (RegistryKey baseKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(hive, RegistryView.Registry32))
        using (RegistryKey key = baseKey.OpenSubKey(subKey))
        {
            if (key != null)
            {
                foreach (string subKeyName in key.GetSubKeyNames())
                {
                    using (RegistryKey subKeyItem = key.OpenSubKey(subKeyName))
                    {
                        string displayName = subKeyItem?.GetValue("DisplayName") as string;
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(displayName))
                        {
                            string path = includePath ? subKeyItem?.GetValue("InstallLocation") as string : string.Empty;
                            values.Add(new ApplicationInfo { Name = displayName, FullPath = path });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `string exePath = Path.Combine(directory, "exeName.exe"); // Replace with the actual executable name or search for it` this is what I wanted in the first place lol, how do I "search for it"?

Comment: check [this](https://pastebin.com/hGEhHMxd) out

Answer (score -1):

This is what I eventually ended up doing, thanks a lot to @katana
Basically, I am just recursively searching for "probable" applications (executables) withing common Windows installation directories, meanwhile ignoring uninstallers, drivers, installers, etc.

```cs
namespace App
{
    class AppInfo
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<string> Executables { get; set; }
    }

    class InstalledApps
    {
        private static List<AppInfo> GetSubKeyValues(RegistryHive hive, string subKey)
        {
            var apps = new List<AppInfo>();
            using (RegistryKey baseKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(hive, RegistryView.Registry32))
            using (RegistryKey key = baseKey.OpenSubKey(subKey))
            {
                if (key != null)
                {
                    foreach (string subKeyName in key.GetSubKeyNames())
                    {
                        using (RegistryKey subKeyItem = key.OpenSubKey(subKeyName))
                        {
                            var displayName = subKeyItem?.GetValue("DisplayName") as string;
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(displayName))
                            {
                                var installLocation = subKeyItem?.GetValue("InstallLocation") as string;
                                apps.AddRange(GetExecutables(installLocation, displayName));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return apps;
        }

        private static bool isValidExeOrDir(string inp)
        {
            string[] ignoreNames = { "unins", "install", "setup", "update", "crash", "error", "service", "help", "upgrade", "report", "driver" };
            return ignoreNames.All(e => !inp.ToLower().Contains(e));
        }

        private static List<AppInfo> GetExecutables(string directoryPath, string appName)
        {
            var apps = new List<AppInfo>();

            string[] ignoreDirs = { "Temp", "Common Files" };

            if (!Directory.Exists(directoryPath) || ignoreDirs.Contains(appName) || !isValidExeOrDir(appName)) { return apps; }

            List<string> dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(directoryPath).ToList();
            dirs.Add(directoryPath);

            foreach (string directory in dirs.ToArray())
            {
                if (!isValidExeOrDir(directory)) { continue; }

                var exeNames = new List<string>();
                try
                {
                    exeNames = new DirectoryInfo(directory).GetFiles()
                                                            .Where(f => f.Extension == ".exe" && isValidExeOrDir(f.Name))
                                                            .Select(f => f.Name)
                                                            .ToList();
                }
                catch { }
                var exePaths = new List<string>();
                if(exeNames == null) { continue; }

                foreach (var exeName in exeNames)
                {
                    exePaths.Add(Path.Combine(directory, exeName));

                }
                apps.Add(new AppInfo { Name = appName, Executables = exePaths });

                try
                {
                    dirs.AddRange(Directory.GetDirectories(directory));
                }
                catch { }
            }

            return apps;
        }

        private static List<AppInfo> GetInstalledAppsFromRegistry()
        {
            var apps = new List<AppInfo>();
            apps.AddRange(GetSubKeyValues(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"));
            apps.AddRange(GetSubKeyValues(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"));
            return apps;
        }

        private static List<AppInfo> GetInstalledAppsFromProgramFiles()
        {
            var apps = new List<AppInfo>();

            // Program Files (32-bit)
            string programFiles86Path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86);
            foreach (var dir in Directory.GetDirectories(programFiles86Path)) {
                apps.AddRange(GetExecutables(dir, Path.GetFileName(dir) + "(x86)"));
            }

            // Program Files (64-bit)
            string programFilesPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles);
            foreach (var dir in Directory.GetDirectories(programFilesPath))
            {
                apps.AddRange(GetExecutables(dir, Path.GetFileName(dir)));
            }

            return apps;
        }

        public static Dictionary<string, List<string>> GetInstalledApplications()
        {
            var installedApps = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

            var apps = new List<AppInfo>();
            apps.AddRange(GetInstalledAppsFromRegistry());
            apps.AddRange(GetInstalledAppsFromProgramFiles());

            foreach (var app in apps)
            {
                installedApps.TryAdd(app.Name, app.Executables.Distinct().ToList());
                if (installedApps.ContainsKey(app.Name))
                {
                    installedApps[app.Name].AddRange(app.Executables.Distinct().ToList());
                    installedApps[app.Name] = installedApps[app.Name].Distinct().OrderBy(e => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(e)).ToList();
                }
            }

            foreach(var installedApp in installedApps)
            {
                if(installedApp.Value.Count == 0)
                {
                    installedApps.Remove(installedApp.Key);
                }
            }

            return installedApps;
        }
    }
}
```

Please feel free to make corrections and suggestions :D